# Getting cursor location within chart during mousewheel event

Tags: c#, charts, mousewheel

I'm trying to get the location of the mouse during a MouseWheel event. In the MouseMove event I have successfully used a HitTest and gone about my business that way but for some reason during the MouseWheel event my HitTest always returns a value of -1 for the HitTest datapoint. Can anyone help me figure this out? I'll include my code below. 
What I am trying to accomplish is a basic zoom-in event with the mousewheel. I want to see the location of the cursor then add 1/4 of the currently viewable chart on either side.

```
    private void chData_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HitTestResult pos = chData.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

            if (e.Delta < 0)
            {
                chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
                chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
            }
            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                double xMin = chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                double xMax = chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;
                double yMin = chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                double yMax = chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;

                double posXStart = pos.PointIndex - (xMax - xMin) / 4;
                double posXFinish = pos.PointIndex + (xMax - xMin) / 4;
                double posYStart = pos.PointIndex - (yMax - yMin) / 4;
                double posYFinish = pos.PointIndex + (yMax - yMin) / 4;

                chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(posXStart, posXFinish);
                chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(posYStart, posYFinish);
            }
        }
        catch { }

    }
```

My chart is called chData by the way. I hope this is just a simple typo somewhere. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So I've figured out that the PointIndex only works when you are actually over a data point. What I need is to know which x-axis value I am at even if I'm not over a data point. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so after a few days of experimentation I finally found something that works. 
I'm going to include my entire code because I know I couldn't find this solution anywhere so I hope this may benefit someone else in the future.

```
private void chData_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Delta < 0)
            {
                chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
                chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
            }

            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                double xMin = chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                double xMax = chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;
                double yMin = chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                double yMax = chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;

                double posXStart = chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) - (xMax - xMin) / 4;
                double posXFinish = chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) + (xMax - xMin) / 4;
                double posYStart = chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) - (yMax - yMin) / 4;
                double posYFinish = chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) + (yMax - yMin) / 4;

                chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(posXStart, posXFinish);
                chData.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(posYStart, posYFinish);
            }
        }
        catch { }            
    }
```

So what this code basically does is zoom in on a chart where you cursor is. It will essentially limit the axis max/min values to be half of what you are currently looking at but centered about the cursor. 
I know there are probably ways to optimize this but for the time being I think this works well enough to get people started. 
I hope this helps!